# Can I convert images to progressive jpeg with filepicker?

Tags: filepicker.io

It would be super helpful if the jpeg files produced by filepicker's handy convert API could produce progressive jpegs. Can it be done already?

Answer (score 0):

We don't currently support progressive jpegs. It's a good idea and I've created a feature request ticket. Thanks.